# Ruby public_send method with hash params where applicable

Tags: ruby, methods

*Tldr: I am trying to use public_send to call methods but some of these methods require arguments as well. How to check which requires arguments and  add those as arguments and include them in the call*

I have an array of methods in a class like this
`class_methods = [:first, :second, :third, :fourth] ...`

I defined a `can_execute` method to check if the class has the method, if so it will execute.

```
def can_execute (class, method_name)
  if class.respond_to?(method_name.to_sym) && class.class_methods.include?(method_name.to_sym)
    class.public_send(method_name)
  end
end
```

When user supplies any of those `class_method` as an argument, I can call them like this
`can_execute(class, method_name)`

Problem is some of those methods accepts hash as arguments, like
`class.first(Value: true)`  or
`class.second(Id: 0, Value: "string")`

But some dont
`class.third`

I am not sure how to include the params hash some of these `class_methods` require?

I do have the option to check what arguments these methods require by calling, `method_args` on them, like

```
class.method_args(:first)
-> [:Value]

class.method_args(:second)
=> [:Id, :Value]

class.method_args(:third)
=> []
```

Comment: You will need to pass arguments to `can_execute(?)` method to use them inside it.

Comment: Why is your `can_execute` also actually _executes_ methods? If you want to keep the behaviour, then yes, simply pass the needed arguments to it.

Comment: separate `can_execute?` and `execute` into two methods or remove `can_` part from the method, cause it makes it ambiguous

Comment: Oh, Andrey, long time no see. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I was on a long'ish vacation (since late December). Getting back to work and, hopefully, to SO :D Glad to read you :)

Comment: Suddenly it feels like I am on Reddit! ;)

Comment: @JagdeepSingh What I am not sure of is some of these methods take multiple hash arguments and I dont know the proper way to dynamically include them in `public_send`. I can easily hard code them individually for each of those methods, problem is I got 4-5 classes each containing 8-10 methods and half of those methods dont take arguments.

Comment: You should add the rails tag! (since you're using class_methods which is rails only)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to pass the arguments to `can_execute` so it can pass them to `public_send`. The splat operator is your friend here. When used as parameter, it will wrap any number of arguments into an array with it's name. When used on an array, it breaks the array down into arguments to pass to a method.

In addition to that, `class` is a keyword. The convention is to call it `klass`, but it can be whatever you want (other than class)

With that in mind, our new method looks like this:

```
def can_execute (klass, method_name, *args)
  if klass.respond_to?(method_name.to_sym) && klass.class_methods.include?(method_name.to_sym)
    klass.public_send(method_name, *args)
  end
end
```

Then to call, it can have parameters or not. No need to check first:

```
can_execute('teststring', :slice, 1, 5) # => "ests"
can_execute('teststring', :upcase) # => "TESTSTRING"
```

If you have another reason to want to check the params, you can use [`Method#arity`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Method.html#method-i-arity) or [`Method#parameters`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Method.html#method-i-parameters). Something like this with results for `#slice`

```
klass.method(method_name.to_sym).arity # => -1
klass.method(method_name.to_sym).parameters # => [[:rest]]
```